# To convert all the digits of a number into the same by switching only one number

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, compare

You are given a binary-like number of zeroes and ones only(INTEGER DATA TYPE).
Question is, can you change the binary number into containing only 0's or 1's by changing **only one number**. Should return false if not possible or if all numbers are already the same.
Is there an efficient way of doing this without importing modules?(I don't mind if there isn't, I just need to know how to do it.)

Some more clarification:

1.I must change only one number to make it all zeroes and all ones.

2.If it already is all zeroes or ones It's false.

**Ex**:

11101:True

11:False

10110:False

So I've tried splitting it into two lists,comparing each value and if they are the same and if they are then it can return ''No''.(Two lists here are lst and ml)

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i]!=lst[j]:
            ml.append(lst[i])
```

But this is a mess and really doesn't help.I then tried using generators,

```
ml=[]
def parse():
    var=[1,1,1,1,0]
    for i in var:    
        yield i
x=parse()
print(x)
while i in x and j in x:
    if x[i]==x[j]:
        ml.append(x[i])
print(ml)
```

But this gives no output at all.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Is that all you needed to know?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I'm sorry for the confusion, but I need the method to do so.I'll edit the post

Comment: Please post your best attempt at solving this and explain any issues you may have run into.  Generally "I need to know" isn't going to make people any more inclined to solve your issue for you, you're still expected to show some kind of effort in attempting to solve your problem first.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco done

Comment: Calling a generator function once returns a generator object. If you want to get all the possible values from `parse()` that would be `x = list(parse())`; but it's really not clear what you want this code to accomplish. Why did you implement this as a generator in the first place if you want to obtain the list of all possible results?

Comment: If the first two digits are equal, see if the remaining list contains exactly one of the other number. If they are different, check if all digits after the third are identical. Finding the number to change wasn't really part of the question, but should be reasonably straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You are given a binary numer.." Of what type???

If it is an integer then it will have a number of bits that is an exact multiple of 8 (one byte), and none of the two examples that you gave; "11101:True, 11:False" meet the criteria for being integers, as they would then instead at least be; "00011101:False, and 00000011:False". So I have to assume that either you are working with strings of ones and zeroes, and not integers (which is very uncommon) or you don't fully understand how numbers are represented in you machine.

However; let's assume that you just made a careless mistake, and really you are dealing with integers, if that is the case then to check if something like this; 10111111 or this 00010000 can be turned "all ones" or "all zeroes" by flipping a single bit you could start by checking the parity of the number (ie. does it have an even or an odd number of ones) if the number has an even parity then it means that there is an even number of ones and hence you either have 11111111 or 00000000 or some combination of 2, 4 or 6 ones and the rest zeroes (if it is a single byte integer) and in that case as per your problem definition you can return False, because either the integer is already all zeroes or all ones, or flipping just one bit would never be enough to make it so as the integer has an even parity.

If the parity is Odd then you need to check whether there is only one "zero" or only one "one" present. In the case that there is only one "one" present, the largest number you will ever get from a single byte is 10000000 = 128, if you have only one zero present then the smallest number you will et from a single byte is 01111111 = 127.

So in the case that you have a single byte with all ones except one zero, then it will have odd parity, and the value will be >=127.

In the case that you have a single byte with all zeroes except one one, then it will have odd parity, and the value will be <=128.

We see that the two cases overlap, but this does not matter, because both values 127 and 128 can only be constructed using one zero or one one, ie. these two values should always return True.

It is worth noting that checking parity is a very fast operation, as it is implemented in the CPU, the same is true for comparing integer values.

```
def can_be_made_even (byte):
    if byte in [127, 128]:
        return True
    if not byte % 2:
        return False
    return True

vals = [0b11011111, 0b10111001, 0b01111111]

for v in vals:
    print(can_be_made_even(v))
```

returns:

```
True
Fale
True
```

In case you need to be able to check integers of varying sizes then you need to add some more code to handle that, and if you need to work with strings instead then you need to do something completely different, but then you need to think about that it even is that you are doing in the first place.

Comment: Rally sorry for that,but I did actually mean integer type values.

Comment: That is also the solution I gave you?